# How to map out parameter in jdbcTemplete.query with BeanPropertyRowMapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring's JdbcTemplate.query() to call Stored Procedure and BeanPropertyRowMapper to map the result set to Bean. My Stored Proc has 2 IN parameter and 2 OUT parameters with multi row RS.  I am able to send the Stored Procedure's IN parameters and map RS to Bean in following way:

```
final String STORED_PROC_NAME= "{CALL MyStoredProc(?,?)}";
 List<MyBean> myBeanList= jdbcTemplate.query(
                    STORED_PROC_NAME,
                    new Object[] { 12, 100 }, //IN PARAMETERS
                    new BeanPropertyRowMapper<MyBean>(MyBean.class)); // RS to Bean Mapper
```

How do I Map OUT parameter. I want to take advantage to BeanPropertyRowMapper